# PHP form not submitted to its caller method

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, xampp

I have installed a complete PHP system that is based on CodeIgniter. Its first view is a form with action set to

```
"<?php echo current_url(); ?>"
```

and this view is shown from a file that defines a class with some methods, a method for each subsequent view. This setup method exists in the directory: `setup/controllers/Setup.php`, while the views shown are in the directory: `setup/views`.

The code that shows the first view is:

```
if ($this->input->post('licence_agreed')) {
        $this->session->set_tempdata('setup_step', 'requirements', $this->setup_timeout);
        redirect('requirements');
    }

    if ( ! file_exists(VIEWPATH .'/license.php')) {
        show_404();
    } else {
        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view('license', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer', $data);
    }
```

The license form is defined as:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST" action="<?php echo current_url(); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="licence_agreed" value="1" />
<div class="terms"><?php echo lang('text_license_terms'); ?></div>
<div class="buttons">
    <p class="text-right"><?php echo lang('text_license_agreed'); ?></p>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo lang('button_continue'); ?></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I load the first view and post the form, it reloads the same view again. I have tried to debug the method above and it seems that it only executes the same `if` condition each time with the same result, regardless of the value of `licence_agreed` parameter.

I can't figure out what is the problem. It works fine on the server. But locally it reloads the same very first view all the time with no action taken.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$this->input->post('licence_agreed')`? Perhaps `var_dump` and then `die`?

Comment: @JimWright when I echo it, it prints an empty string

Comment: Do you POST or GET your form?

Comment: @kerbholz It is a POST form

Comment: Update your question with the whole form

Comment: @AmaniElsaed solved ??

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Not yet!! I have been trying to fix it for more than two days but not solved till now

Comment: @AmaniElsaed whats your controller name and method ? and is this HMVC?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I explained it in the question. When I post the form, it doesn't redirect to the action. It just reloads the same form again. Simply I think the action is not executed or the form input value is not received.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam It extends Base_Controller and the method that loads the license view - first view - is index().

Comment: @AmaniElsaed nop. i asked where this form should get submit ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162905/discussion-between-amani-elsaed-and-abdulla-nilam).